# Complex filter in sqlite

Tags: sqlite

I have a database that looks like that:

```
No.     |Item   |Fx         |Fy         |Fxy
-------------------------------------------------
1       |a      |1.865      |-2.650     |-1.982
2       |a      |0.816      |-2.742     |-1.287
3       |a      |1.779      |-3.366     |-2.188
4       |b      |-0.367     |-0.229     |2.243
5       |b      |-0.413     |0.736      |1.889
6       |c      |-1.150     |0.150      |1.637
7       |c      |-1.817     |-1.003     |3.429
```

What I want is to apply a comparative filter which has to do the following (in pseudo-code):

```
for each distinct item "k":
    go through all rows with "k" and:
      remove row "i" if row "j" exists with: Fx_j < Fx_i AND Fy_j < Fy_i AND abs(Fxy_j) > abs(Fxy_i)
```

The application of the above filter for the sample given above would yield the following:

```
No.     |Item   |Fx         |Fy         |Fxy
-----------------------------------------------
1       |a      |1.865      |-2.650     |-1.982  <-- leaves due to 3
2       |a      |0.816      |-2.742     |-1.287  <--survives
3       |a      |1.779      |-3.366     |-2.188  <--survives
4       |b      |-0.367     |-0.229     |2.243   <--survives
5       |b      |-0.413     |0.736      |1.889   <--survives
6       |c      |-1.150     |0.150      |1.637   <-- leaves due to 7
7       |c      |-1.817     |-1.003     |3.429   <--survives
```

My filter is implemented in Python atm. I am querying the database (SELECT * FROM table GROUP BY Item) and I then filter the results.

The problem with my approach is that it takes a really long time since the database is a couple of GBs big. I was wondering whether a better way exists comprising optimally solely of a probably complex sqlite statement.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The follwing SQL query *seems* to do what you want.

```
SELECT t.No, t.Item, t.Fx, t.Fy, t.Fxy FROM data_table t
EXCEPT
SELECT a.No, a.Item, a.Fx, a.Fy, a.Fxy FROM
  data_table a
  INNER JOIN data_table b ON b.Item = a.Item AND a.No <> b.No
    AND b.Fx < a.Fx
    AND b.Fy < a.Fy
    AND ABS(b.Fxy) > ABS(a.Fxy)
```

Docs: [SQLite Compound Select Statements](https://www.sqlite.org/syntax/compound-select-stmt.html)

There might be implications in how the data is indexed. Experiment with different clustered indexes. Intuitively I would expect clustering by `(Item, No)` to yield the best results, but whether that's feasible or not for your use case depends on how often rows are added or removed in the table.

Comment: Would you mind guiding me through the structure of your query? Like briefly. You `select` all **except for** some rows. The excluded rows are the ones given by the `inner join` which joins two copies of the same table.Right?

Comment: Regarding EXCEPT: Does this help? https://www.techonthenet.com/sqlite/except.php You can run the second statement on its own to see what it selects.

Comment: It takes 1,546 sec to run in my computer which is significantly better than my solution involving Python. The database i am using it at has 6,669,048 rows. What troubles me now is that the rows returned by the two approaches are not the same (616,780 vs 637,871). Thanks thought!

Comment: Well, that's why I wrote "seems". What good is a fast solution that is incorrect? If you post a data sample where this SQL does not work as expected, I will look into it.